# How to split the content of xmlhttp.response in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, split

i did manage to build a code that works and it does the splitting when added manually:

```
var input = '10;11;15;16';
    var arr = input.split(';');

    // update the content of the div with ID "humid"
    document.getElementById('humid').textContent = arr[0];
    document.getElementById('humid').style.width = `${arr[0]}%`;
    document.getElementById('temp').textContent = arr[1];
    document.getElementById('temp').style.width = `${arr[1]}%`;
    document.getElementById('uv').textContent = arr[2];
    document.getElementById('uv').style.width = `${arr[2]}%`;
    document.getElementById('info').textContent = arr[3];
    document.getElementById('info').style.width = `${arr[3]}%`;
```

the problem i have is that i want to use the data from this XMLHttpRequest,

this is how i get my value:

```
function readForestall() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("ForestAll").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "readFORESTALL", false);
        xhttp.send();
        }



 setInterval(function() {
      readForestall();
    }, 5000);
```

i did try a lot of things with no result, like this:

```
var input = 'ForestAll';
or input = document.getElementById('ForestAll').value
```

regards

Comment: No clue what `input = document.getElementById('ForestAll').value` has to do with the split code or the Ajax call. So the responseText has an input?

Comment: So why isn't it just `var input = this.responseText; var arr = input.split(';'); document.getElementById('humid').textContent = arr[0];` inside of the onreadystatechange???

Comment: thnaks for your reply, well im still learning... so i did ask nicely..... that what u said does work for now, i gonna test some more before i can say its good..thanks and  regards